# get string using split in c#

Tags: c#, string

Give the string `Metal_In` I have to extract the `Metal` part

I'm doing the following now:

```
DropDownList ddl = ctrl as DropDownList;
if(ddl != null)
{
    ddl.ID = ddl.ID.Split('_')[1].ToString();   
}
```

Comment: I think I managed to extract what the OP meant with my last edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of index `1` use index `0` *(it can be done in a better way)*. Also you don't need `ToString` at the end as it is already a string.

```
dl.ID = ddl.ID.Split('_')[0].ToString();
```

You may check for array length before using index and .ToString

```
string[] tempArray = ddl.ID.Split('_');
if(tempArray.Length > 0)
    ddl.ID = tempArray[0];
```

`ddl.ID.Split('_')[1]` will give you the 2nd part of the string which is `In`. Remember the array index starts with `0`

Answer (score 1):

With the string Metal_In, call `Split` ( broken out example below ).

```
string[] elems = ddl.ID.Split('_');

// elems contains two elements
// 0 - Metal
// 1 - in
```

To get the value of Metal, use subscript 0 to get the first element.

```
string firstPart = elems[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it can be assumed that Metal word exists in original string,

```
var item = ddl.Id.Split('_)[0]
```

Otherwise go with Habib's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FirstOrDefault`, it will handle the array issues.

```
ddl.ID = ddl.ID.Split('_').FirstOrDefault();
```

It will return null in case of empty array.